# Keras training performance slower on GPU than CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I just started learning deep learning a couple of days ago. 
I am trying to train a CNN using a dataset consist of cat and dog pics.

But the problem is the training process is taking too long on CPU and also I can see my CPU utilization not increased noticeably during training. And also the training process is running very slow. I thought it is because of CPU, So I proceed to install CUDA and TensorFlow-gpu, Tensorflow-gpu seems to work as the graphics card showing up on the console.

```
Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4620 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:1c:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
```

but the training speed seems to be slower on GPU than on CPU.

And also while training the model it taking all GPU memory but GPU utilization seems to be very low while training. Can you guys please check what am I doing wrong? and how can I speed up things?

**SYSTEM SPECS:**

CPU: Ryzen 2700x

GPU: ZOTAC RTX 2060

RAM: DDR4 16GB 3000 MHZ

**THE CODE I AM USING:**

```
import keras as keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adadelta', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 35,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 20)

print("================== Saving Model ==========================")
classifier.save('./model.h5')
print("=================  Model Saved  ==========================")
```

SPEED:

```
  20/8000 [..............................] - ETA: 10:47 - loss: 0.0269 - acc: 0.9906
```

Comment: steps_per_epoch should be the length of your training set, divided by the batch size https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator

Comment: It seems like, it using fewer images for training now.

Comment: Why are you saying that? can you explain?

Comment: Well, please don't get me wrong, Each step takes more time now. But after 10th epoch, the accuracy is much lower than the current code. that's way.